# import pandas results in ModuleNotFoundError :_lzma

Tags: pandas, python-3.7, ubuntu-18.04, lzma

On Ubuntu 18.04 with python 3.7.3, I'm attempting to import pandas but this fails because it can't find `_lzma`.

I've verified that `_lzma` is installed with dpkg:

> /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so. Oddly, _lzma is not a dependency of pandas (as specified by pip3).

Comment: You have multiple python installed?

Answer (score 18):

I have the same issue using `pyenv`. You don't need to rollback `pandas`.

To fix import errors, I've removed python:

`$ pyenv uninstall 3.7.1`

Installed dependencies:

`$ sudo apt-get install liblzma-dev`

and reinstalled version:

`$ pyenv install 3.7.1`

More on this dependencies [here](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment)

Comment: Tried this for version 3.7.4, run into AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'

Comment: @Ben, have you installed all dependencies from [this link](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment)? I've no issues with 3.7.4 either.

Comment: alternative source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27532#issuecomment-514044754

Comment: @Jeff Xiao and kiba:  Thank you. Actually, I was missing one of the Mint dependencies from the pyenv installation instructions (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment). Reinstalling 3.7.4 with pyenv after installing dependencies fixed it. Sorry about that!

Comment: You have to roll back `pandas` if you don't have `sudo` access.

Answer (score 17):

I was running into this exact same issue today! I was able to fix it though.

Pandas just put out a new version `0.25.0` on July 18th and changing the version back to `0.24.2` fixed this issue for me.

I hope this works for you too!

link: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Answer (score -1):

just upgraded to version 0.25.1 and works well